# Format numbers with comma and get the total value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my script, I have a table in which I'm getting the total value per column.
What I want to achieve is to display the numbers with a comma.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t) {
  var n = this,
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
    i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))),
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
  return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".num1, .num2, .num3").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });
});


function calculateSum() {
  var tot1 = 0;
  var tot2 = 0;
  var tot3 = 0;

  // Paying 


  $(".num1").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot1 += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  $("input[name='tot1']").val(tot1.formatMoney(2, '.', ','));


  $(".num2").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot2 += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  $("input[name='tot2']").val(tot2.formatMoney(2, '.', ','));

  $(".num3").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot3 += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  //$("input[name='tot3']").val(tot3.toFixed(2));
  $("input[name='tot3']").val(tot3.formatMoney(2, '.', ','));




}
window.onload = calculateSum();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>COL1</th>
      <th>COL2</th>
      <th>COL3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="num1" name="num1" value="1200.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num2" name="num2" value="500.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num3" name="num3" value="100.00" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="num1" name="num1" value="900.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num2" name="num2" value="1500.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num3" name="num3" value="10.00" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="num1" name="num1" value="200.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num2" name="num2" value="500.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num3" name="num3" value="300.00" /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="tot1" name="tot1" value="" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="tot2" name="tot2" value="" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="tot3" name="tot3" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean you want to display the numbers with comma?

Comment: Aren't commas being added already to the sum? Review the demo

Comment: I think its only added in the jsfiddle automatically.

Comment: Unsurprisingly - the code posted in the question is not the same as the code posted in the fiddle

Comment: @clever_bassi I mean I want also the displayed numbers in my table to format with commas

Comment: for any numbers you need to be displayed with commas just use `localeToString` as I've demonstrated in my answer below

Comment: Do you have any server side logic?  Like PHP?

Comment: @AdamAzad I have a script that added the comma to the sum. What I mean is I want also the displayed numbers in my table to format with commas

Comment: @user2182349 asp.net.

Comment: so, you need to read the numbers from the inputs, remove commas, use this value to parseFloat, then write the number back with commas using your method or toLocaleString

Comment: @JaromandaX but how? I mean yeah I have also that though but I actually didn't know.

Comment: use page load element blur and/or element change events

Comment: @x'tian, do you mean, all numbers in the table must be Formatted as your Answer's format: '**2,300.00**'.. is it?

Comment: @Vikrant Hmmm as to my private message to you. I'm actually not referring to this question. Hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change value of input in `calculateSum()` as,

```
$(".num1").each(function () {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        tot1 += parseFloat(this.value);
        num1 = parseFloat(this.value);
        this.value = num1.formatMoney(2, '.', ',');
    }
});    
$("input[name='tot1']").val(tot1.formatMoney(2, '.', ','));
```

Take a look at the snippet:

```js
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t) {
  var n = this,
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
    i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))),
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
  return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".num1, .num2, .num3").each(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });
});

function calculateSum() {
  var tot1 = 0;
  var tot2 = 0;
  var tot3 = 0;
  var num1 = 0;
  var num2 = 0;
  var num3 = 0;
  // Paying 
  $(".num1").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot1 += parseFloat(this.value);
      num1 = parseFloat(this.value);
      this.value = num1.formatMoney(2, '.', ',');
    }
  });
  $("input[name='tot1']").val(tot1.formatMoney(2, '.', ','));

  $(".num2").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot2 += parseFloat(this.value);
      num2 = parseFloat(this.value);
      this.value = num2.formatMoney(2, '.', ',');
    }
  });
  $("input[name='tot2']").val(tot2.formatMoney(2, '.', ','));

  $(".num3").each(function() {
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot3 += parseFloat(this.value);
      num3 = parseFloat(this.value);
      this.value = num3.formatMoney(2, '.', ',');
    }
  });
  //$("input[name='tot3']").val(tot3.toFixed(2));
  $("input[name='tot3']").val(tot3.formatMoney(2, '.', ','));
}

window.onload = calculateSum();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>COL1</th>
      <th>COL2</th>
      <th>COL3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="num1" name="num1" value="1200.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num2" name="num2" value="500.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num3" name="num3" value="100.00" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="num1" name="num1" value="900.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num2" name="num2" value="1500.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num3" name="num3" value="10.00" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="num1" name="num1" value="200.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num2" name="num2" value="500.00" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="num3" name="num3" value="300.00" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="tot1" name="tot1" value="" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="tot2" name="tot2" value="" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="tot3" name="tot3" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) as follows(or like in [this forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zavy7t9u/)):

```
$(".num1").each(function () {
  if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot1     += parseFloat(this.value);
  }
});
$("input[name='tot1']").val(tot1.toLocaleString());


$(".num2").each(function () {
  if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot2+= parseFloat(this.value);
  }
});
$("input[name='tot2']").val(tot2.toLocaleString());

$(".num3").each(function () {
  if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      tot3+= parseFloat(this.value);
  }
});
$("input[name='tot3']").val(tot3.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, he's got code that does that even in IE10 and earlier!

Comment: @JaromandaX: didn't see the use of toLocaleString specifically although there was a rather complex method that was using RegExps to switch out the dots with commas

Comment: my point was that a) code here doesn't match his code in fiddle, and b) toLocaleString only works in IE version 11 (and all other good browsers)

Comment: Id just want to get the sum of two values with comma like 1,00.00 + 20,000.00.

Comment: I've provided you with a solution, have you tried it?